# Jupyter Notebook HOw can i assign a default value to datepicker and sort the time within the selected date?

Tags: python-3.x, datepicker, jupyter-notebook

I can try to set condition some data that is within the time picker in the datepicker. I got two problem

MY code was

```
def show_filter_date(start ,end):
        print(start_dater.value)
    print(end_dater.value)
    time_df = (id_one[(id_one['_source.timestampstring']>pd.to_datetime(start))&(id_one['_source.timestampstring']<pd.to_datetime(end))])
    #print(time_df.head(20))
#    time_df = (id_one[(id_one['_source.timestampstring']>pd.to_datetime(start_dater.value))&(id_one['_source.timestampstring']<pd.to_datetime(end_dater.value))])
    time_df.head(20)
    
layout = widgets.Layout(width='auto', height='40px')
start_dater = widgets.DatePicker(description='Pick a Start Date',disabled=False)
end_dater = widgets.DatePicker(description='Pick an End Date',disabled=False )
#display(widgets.HBox((start_dater, end_dater)))
#display(start_dater)
#display(end_dater)
#id_one.head()
#combine_date = widgets.HBox((start = start_dater, end = end_dater))
#country_selector =  widgets.Dropdown(
interact(show_filter_date,start = start_dater , end = end_dater)
```

1. everytime i run the code it show Error
   "Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and NoneType"

I have tried to assign default value like

```
start_dater = widgets.DatePicker(description='Pick a Start Date',disabled=False, year = 2020 ,month = 12, day = 1)
```

but it won't change to `2020/12/01`

So, how can I get a value other than null?

2. I fail in interact for the datepicker in which

A)    `print(time_df.head(20))`

B)

```
time_df = (id_one[(id_one['_source.timestampstring']>pd.to_datetime(start_dater.value))&(id_one['_source.timestampstring']<pd.to_datetime(end_dater.value))])

time_df.head(20)
```

Only (A) can be "interact" or "refresh" when I pick a day but not (B)

And for Question 2, when I put time_df.head(20) in the NEXT CELL it does work tho.......

But what i want is to show the result like in time_df

I would appreciate if any help

the `id_one` is something like

```
Index           _source.hdrrId  _source.hdrfId  _source.hdrType  \
199            1300                1234                     1  

_source.timestampstring   
199 2020-11-06 09:36:04.800
```

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: can you provide a sample for your input data `id_one`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I replicated your first error with

```
id_one = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('20200101','20200202'), columns = ['_source.timestampstring'])
```

This is because you did not set a default value for the DatePicker. The value is None by default hence the error. Here is the fix (value argument is the default value):

```
start_dater = widgets.DatePicker(description='Pick a Start Date',disabled=False, value = datetime.date(2020,1,1))
end_dater = widgets.DatePicker(description='Pick an End Date',disabled=False, value = datetime.date(2020,2,1))
```

I cannot replicate your second error. My guess is you put print *before* the `time_df =` statement. You need to put the print *after* the line that calculates `time_df`

Comment: I think the reason for the bug is the same. Did my reply solve the problem?

Comment: thanks you your help~ yes the default value answer solved